# horizontal slider bug - more than one horizontal slider with same classes with native JavaScript , All slider working together how I can solve it

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

#horizontal slider bug - more than one horizontal slider with same classes  with native JavaScript, All slider working together how I can solve it#
##[This First Horizontal Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiEBL.png)##
'''
/* Declare Variables */

```
    let moveRight = document.querySelectorAll('.move-right');
    let moveLeft = document.querySelectorAll('.move-left');
    let left = document.querySelector('.move-left');
    let right = document.querySelector('.move-right');
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    let x = 0;

    /* Function to slide Sliders Divs To left when click on arrow with class = ".move- 
  left"*/
    for(let i = 0; i < moveLeft.length; i++){
     moveLeft.forEach(function(left){
        left.addEventListener('click', function(){

        x++;
        for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
            if(x==0) {slides[i].style.left = "0px";}
            if(x==1) {slides[i].style.left = "-320px";}
            if(x==2) {slides[i].style.left = "-640px";}
            if(x==3) {slides[i].style.left = "-960px";}
            if(x==4) {slides[i].style.left = "-1280px";}
            if(x==5) {slides[i].style.left = "-1600px";}

            if(x>5) {x=5;}
        }
      })});
    }
   /* Function to slide Sliders Divs To Right  when click on arrow with class = ".move- 
  right"*/

    for(let i = 0; i < moveRight.length; i++){
      moveRight.forEach(function(right){
        right.addEventListener('click', function(){

        x--;
        for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
            if(x==0) {slides[i].style.left = "0px";}
            if(x==1) {slides[i].style.left = "-320px";}
            if(x==2) {slides[i].style.left = "-640px";}
            if(x==3) {slides[i].style.left = "-960px";}
            if(x==4) {slides[i].style.left = "-1280px";}

       if(x < 0) {x=0;}

  }
 })});
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the HTML code but I assume you have a section or div tag inside of which you have your slides and the left/right buttons. You can modify your code a bit so that you target slides only in the container. In this way, even if you have multiple sliders, only that slider will work whose buttons you click.

```
left.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    // Assuming the parent div has a class of container
    const container = event.target.closest('.container');
    // Selecting only those slides that are a part of the container where the button has been clicked
    const slides = container.querySelectorAll('.slides');
    // Rest of your logic goes here
});
```

The HTML would be something like this

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='slide'>Content here</div>
    <button class='move-left'>Left</button>
    <button class='move-right'>Right</button>
</div>
```

Note: [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) does not work in IE and you may have to add a polyfill for it if you wish to support IE.